# Valgrind like tool on Mac OS 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: c, macos, memory-leaks

I need a tool which helps me to find memory leaks in a c program in a similar way valgrind does. It should figures out when a program overwrites memory it should not (e.g. by miscalculating an array index). I learned that there is the leaks utility along with the graphical instruments app.

However I think it can just find memory allocated with new (or malloc) which was not released and is not accessible anymore. Also I learned that valgrind is supposed to work on older releases (10.5 and 10.6), but I use lion (10.7).

Comment: As written above it does not (yet) work with lion (10.7).

Comment: @Mat : Lion (10.7) is not supported yet as OP pointed out, they are working on it since june, but it doesn't seem so easy : https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=275168

Comment: From your link @Matthieu, it seems as though people have gotten it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the XCode developer tool ***MallocDebug***.  You should have this installed with XCode in your */Developer* folder

Alternatively, you can run your application in ***gdb*** and use the native malloc logging by running

```
% gdb <program name>
(gdb) set env MallocStackLoggingNoCompact 1
(gdb) run
```

Then, you can use `/usr/bin/leaks` and `/usr/bin/malloc_history` to find obvious leaks

Comment: Tested it in a case where I accidentally multiplied 2 vars in an array access instead of adding them. w/o MallocStackLoggingNoCompact the bt output is useless, but after having set that it told me the exact line! Thx for the hint!

Comment: However I couldn't find MallocDebug in 10.7. Also shark is gone.. :(

Comment: Looks like MallocDebug has been replaced by the `Leaks` instrument in the `Instruments` application.

Answer (score 8):

Valgrind 3.7.0 (released 5<sup>th</sup> November 2011) supports Lion. http://valgrind.org

Comment: It is straight-forward to download, build and use it, too.